Matlab docker microservice in compose issue
I created a microservice in MATLAB according to following how-to and it works as expected:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/mps_dev_test/create-a-microservice-docker-image.html
I built a web-app, which shall use that ML-container and retrieves data from it. When I run both containers independently, communication works as expected.
I now had the plan to put them into a docker-compose and start-up my application via compose. This is the compose-file, that I currently use:
services:
  web:
    image: web_app:latest
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - MLSL_URI=http://mlsl:9910
  mlsl:
    image: mlsl_server:latest
    ports:
      - "9900:9910"
    container_name: mlsl

I now face following issue:

web-container cannot access the ML-container's necessary service via the internal port - I receive HTTP404

I use following endpoint for that http://mlsl:9910/functionarchive/convertData



I tried following things:

I checked the external endpoint of the container via http://mlsl:9900/api/health and received HTTP200
the service of the ML-container is still accessible and I receive data via the external port
via http://mlsl:9900/functionarchive/convertData
I checked the internal endpoint of the internal network of the container via http://mlsl:9910/api/health and receive a HTTP403, indicating permission issues

So I am quite stuck. Is there any way to access the services inside the docker network or is it just possible to access the public docker port of the ML-container? Do I need to change the container build settings in ML/SL? I used the settings as mentioned in the how-to of ML/SL.
